# Create map from two lists with key and value as same object

Tags: java, lambda, stream

I have 2 lists which contain Objects. These 2 lists can have same Objects in different order.

I have overridden the equals method in the Object such that if one particular property of the object is same as other Object then they are equal even if other properties are not same.

Now I need to create a map where the key is the Object from one list and value is the same Object from the other list. If there is an Object in one list which does not have an equal object in the other list, those Objects should be ignored while creating the Map.

How can i accomplish this using java stream?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Do you even need the first list?  Can't you just arrange the objects in the second list into a map, where the key is the property that needs to match?

Comment: If you have two lists with the same objects, you can just remove one and you don't lose any information.

Comment: `key is the Object from one list and value is the same Object from the other list.` do you really need a map when a key exact the same as a value?

Comment: @dehasi if you read my question even though the object is same (override equals) there are properties which have different values

Comment: @gechu is there a guarantee that only one object from the second list corresponds to only one object from the first list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see why you want to do something like this, but it seems very hacky.  I'm sure if you tell us what you're trying to achieve, we can provide you with a better design.  Regardless, the following will work with Java 10:

```
var list1 = List.of("One", "Two", "Three");
var list2 = List.of("Two", "Three", "Four");

var set = Set.copyOf(list2);

var map = list1.stream()
               .filter(set::contains)
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> list2.get(list2.indexOf(v))));

System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{Two=Two, Three=Three}
```

The equivalent code written for Java 8 is as follows:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("Two", "Three", "Four");

Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list2);

// Defined the Map here for formatting reasons.
Map<String, String> map;

map = list1.stream()
           .filter(set::contains)
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> list2.get(list2.indexOf(v))));

System.out.println(map);
```

**Note**: This assumes that you have overridden `Object#hashCode` as well as `Object#equals`.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. If both the Objects are same(one property same) and if other properties are different I need to do some operations like editing a file. The other option was to loop through the list and find the same Object in the other list, I thought creating a map might be a better option.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought.  If you need me to rewrite this to work with a version other than Java 10, let me know!

Comment: Just want to understand the code, how does this statement list2.get(list2.indexOf(v)) make sure it is getting the same object as the first list?

Comment: @gechu Well `list2.indexOf(v)` gets the index of the first object equal to `v` in `list2`.  Then, `list2.get(...)` actually gets the element from that index within `list2`.